# How to specify directory where the RootNamespace should be?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, namespaces

If I have a project with the `RootNamespace` `AwesomeRoot`, and I want a class to be directly in that namespace, the way I've always done this is to put the class's code file directly into the project directory (not sure if I have that terminology right, but I mean  the directory where the `*.csproj` file is). And if I want some other class to be in the namespace `AwesomeRoot.PrettyGreatSubnamespace`, I would put that class's code file in the `PrettyGreatSubnamespace` of the project directory.

Doing it this way, if there's a mismatch between the path of a class file and the namespace of that class, Visual Studio will give me an `IDE0130` warning, "Namespace does not match folder structure", and furthermore offers a quick and easy automatic fix. Also, when I create a new class, VS automatically sets the namespace appropriately based on the file path.

That's all great, but what I'd really like is to have the source code based in a "Source" subdirectory of the project directory, and have code that's in that directory correspond to the `RootNamespace`. So I'd have `AwesomeRoot` classes in `<project>\Source`, and `AwesomeRoot.PrettyGreatSubnamespace` code in `<project>\Source\PrettyGreatSubnamespace`.

Unfortunately, if I just do that naively, VS will expect the appropriate namespaces to be `AwesomeRoot.Source` and `AwesomeRoot.Source.PrettyGreatNamespace`. I do *not* want this `Source` level in all my namespaces. Nor do I want to be constantly fighting against the IDE. Nor do I want to turn off the `IDE0130` warning and the other features that enable this stuff.

I imagine that there's a way (in the project file?) to say "the base directory of the root namespace should be such-and-such", and have everything else just work the way it always has. Unfortunately, I've thus far been unable to find such a way. How can this be done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please share more screenshots and give a minimal reproduce demo(which is not in production.) From my side, I can not see any relationship with directory, renaming  namespace is no problem. Could you please just share non-production codes that able to reproduce the issue, that will help others understand this issue. :)

Comment: That's a bit an unusual layout, so I'm not sure that's supported. The suggested path structure is rather  `source\project\` (with the csproj sitting in the project folder). Then it works just fine.

Comment: @PMF, I'm not sure I understand "That's a bit of an unusual layout": Do you mean the layout I normally use, or the change I want to make to it? Because the layout I normally use is what VS creates for me by default when I make a new project: It makes a directory under the solution's directory for the project (say, "pdir"`), a project file directly in there ("pdir\pdir.csproj"), and some cheesy little initial class, also directly in there ("pdir\Class1.cs"). The Class1.cs is automatically given the root namespace. Not sure where the "suggested path structure" you mention comes from?

Comment: [`IDE0130` style rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0130) can be configured in the [EditorConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files) file to be disabled for specific directories. There does not seem to be a way to map `Source` to `AwesomeRoot` but you can disable the style rule for `<project>` and for `Source`.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT, please see my reply to PMF from a moment ago; I hope that will clear it up a bit. VS does all this stuff automatically (except allowing me to specify the top level directory that will correspond to the root namespace).

Comment: @JonathanDodds, thanks, but I don't want to disable the rule. I like the rule. I just don't want to fight against it constantly, and my issue is that there doesn't seem to be a way to say where the code of the default namespace goes - it just always automatically goes directly into the project directory.

Comment: @PMF Are you thinking of a `source` directory with different project repos? That's not the question here.

Comment: @BobVesterman I'm not suggesting disabling the rule. I'm suggesting tailoring the directories where the rule is applied.

Comment: @JonathanDodds, the IDE0310 thing is just a small part of the issue. All disabling it does is getting rid of the autofix suggestion. VS will still automatically create classes inside of the Source directory to be in the namespace AwesomeRoot\Source, and those inside of Source\Whatever to be in the namespace  AwesomeRoot\Source\Whatever.

Comment: @BobVesterman Yea, I was suggesting to add the "source" folder as first level. So you have `\AwesomeSolution\source\AwesomeProject1...X` instead of `\AwesomeSolution\AweSomeProjext1..X\source`.

Comment: @PMF, oh, I see. I should back up a little, I think: The reason I want to do this is because for projects with a bunch of different subnamespaces, having directories for each of them directly in the same directory as everything else for the project (for example, Docs, bin, obj) gets somewhat problematic from an organization/disorganization point of view. I'd rather have (say) Docs and Source rather than Docs and SomeSubnamespace and SomeOtherSubnamespace and YetAnotherSubnamespace and and and.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, I don't know whether there's an option to make things work exactly the way you want them, but you can use a directory structure like this to separate code from other data:

```
\ (Project root)
-- Awesomeproject.sln
-- \build
-- \documentation
  -- Specification.doc
  -- Readme.txt
-- \src
  -- \AwesomeProject1
     -- AwesomeProject1.csproj
     -- \namespace1
     -- \namespace2
  -- \AwesomeLibrary1
     -- AwesomeLibrary1.csproj
     -- \namespace...
-- \bin
-- \obj
```

There can be any number of folders between solution and it's projects (and the projects can be spread to many folders), but not between the project file and it's subfolders.

Comment: Thanks @PMF. I understood after your earlier "Yea, I was suggesting" comment, but didn't really want to split the things that belong to a project away from that project (for example, I'd like ```Project1\src" and "Project1\docs", rather than "src\Project1" and "docs\Project1". But this is very close to what I want, and having thought about it some more overnight, I now think that the little difference between it and what I want wouldn't be so bad. I'll keep looking around for a way to do exactly what I want, but if I don't find one, I'll probably wind up using your suggestion.